# Login system node.js and firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to make a registration code, and login with firebase-admin. For the registration part it works but for the login part I can't solve the errors if someone could help me please. THANKS :

```js
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./config.json');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const nouvelUtilisateur = req.body;
  try {
    const userRecord = await auth.createUser({
      email: nouvelUtilisateur.email,
      password: nouvelUtilisateur.password
    });
    await db.collection("users").add({ uid: userRecord.uid, email: userRecord.email });
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Utilisateur ajouté avec succès' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Une erreur s'est produite :", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur lors de l\'ajout de l\'utilisateur' });
  }
});

app.post('/connexion', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const userRecord = await auth.getUserByEmail(email);
    const isPasswordValid = await auth.verifyPassword(password, userRecord.passwordHash);

    if (isPasswordValid) {
      res.json({ message: 'Connexion réussie', user: userRecord });
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Mot de passe incorrect' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur lors de la connexion :', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur serveur' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serveur démarré sur le port ${port}`);
});
```

I have tried several methods to try to solve this problem unfortunately nothing is conclusive and I am still stuck at this level

Comment: I have now new error : Erreur lors de la connexion : TypeError: auth.comparePassword is not a function

Answer (score -1):

I see that you're trying to implement user registration and login using Firebase Authentication and Firestore with the firebase-admin package in a Node.js Express application. The code you provided looks mostly correct, but there's a small issue in your login logic. Firebase Authentication does not provide a direct verifyPassword function. Instead, you can use the comparePassword function along with auth().getUserByEmail to verify the password. Here's the corrected version of your login endpoint:

```
app.post('/connexion', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const userRecord = await auth.getUserByEmail(email);

    // Use Firebase Auth's built-in function to compare passwords
    const isPasswordValid = await auth.comparePassword(password, userRecord);

    if (isPasswordValid) {
      res.json({ message: 'Connexion réussie', user: userRecord });
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Mot de passe incorrect' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur lors de la connexion :', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur serveur' });
  }
});
```

Please replace the auth.verifyPassword line with the auth.comparePassword line as shown above.

Additionally, ensure that you have properly configured Firebase Authentication and Firestore in your Firebase project, and that your config.json file contains the correct service account credentials. Make sure that your Firebase project is properly set up to use the same Firebase configuration details in both your client and server code.

If you still encounter issues, please provide the specific error messages you are encountering so that I can help you debug further.

Comment: I have now new error : Erreur lors de la connexion : TypeError: auth.comparePassword is not a function